# Do I need OpenCV build with Gstreamer to use Gstreamer in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, video-streaming, gstreamer

I am trying to send `cv::Mat` frames via RTSP.
I created a working project in Visual Studio using GStreamer using this [gst-rtsp-server](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-video.c) code. I am able to receive test video of GStreamer using VLC.

Now I am trying to send a video via OpenCV by reading it frame by frame using `cv::VideoCapture`

But my OpenCV is built without GStreamer support? How can I use the GStreamer library to send Opencv frames via RTSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture frames using OpenCV with gstreamer backend, you will need to build OpenCV with Gstreamer. Afterwards you will need to pass your apiPreference `cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER` as second argument to `cv::VideoCapture()`. For example: `cv::VideoCapture(filename,cv::CAP_GSTREAMER)`.

Comment: I am capturing frames using FFmpeg. I just want to send it using GStreamer. Can I do that without building openCV with GStreamer?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You'll need to build with GStreamer.

Comment: Ok. Is there any good tutorial for building opencv with gstreamer for Windows, Visual studios? I tried this but it is giving me errors. https://medium.com/@galaktyk01/how-to-build-opencv-with-gstreamer-b11668fa09c